# Notification fromClient1 to Client2 through WCF

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, service, windows-services

I'm new at WCF and I've got one problem, and I don't have an idea how to solve it.

I've got Windows Service app listening to COM ports, and GUI WPF app for configuring Windows Service app. Among that my idea is to send notification to WPF app every time when something comes to COM port and maybe send that data to WPF.

For communicaton between those two clients I use WCF, and for sending data from WCF service to WPF app I got to use callbacks.

I got to use two different ServiceContracts because of two different clients. One of ServiceContacts supports callback method, and one of them not so there are two different bindings.

Is there any way to invoke callback method implemented on WPF app when WS gets data from COM port. On WS I invoke proxy method defined in ServiceContract for WS, and get data in WCF service but when I invoke callback its always null. I know that there is problem with OperationContext and I know what problem is but I dont know how to solve it, or is there any way to solve it.

Please help me and thank you.

Comment: callback contract seems the proper way to go. If you have a problem with it, you need to describe that problem. "I know that there is problem" will yield no answer.

Comment: My definition of callback method is defined in serviceContract1 and I got to invoke it from ServiceContract2 method. Problem is I cant implement callback method because I cant get right OperationContext(where the method is implemented) in that method and when I invoke callback it's always null. My problem is how to get Client1 OperationContext in Client2 ServiceContact method. My opinion is that it's not possible but Im WCF newbee so I ask :). If you understand problem now please help. :)))

Comment: post some code and indicate where it goes wrong. Also I still don't understand what two servicecontracts are you talking about and why. Simplify the problem to its very core.

Comment: I have one service and two different clients ws and wpf...ws is listening to ports and sends recieved data to service...service sends that data to DB and if wpf client is open service forwards data to wpf...thats the plan...callback methods if I understood them well are made for "sending feedback info"...I dont need feedback...I need to call callback method implemented in wpf from method defined in ws serviceContract...that means that i have to get wpf operation context in ws operation context...i dont think its possible but there must be a way to implement this...

Comment: I still think duplex WCF (i.e. contract with Callback) is one way to go if your WFP client is normally calling the "service" via WCF anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think duplex WCF (i.e. contract with Callback) is one way to go if your WFP client is normally calling the "service" via WCF anyway. You will obtain the callback context in the "service" contract class (its constructor usually) and then use it to forward anything to the WPF client at any time. Google "Duplex WCF".

However this is a situation for which in enterprise scale you will use a middleware solution, i.e. a separate "message queue/bus" infrastructure to which the WPF clients subscribe and get their updates. If no one is subscribed, messages are sent to /dev/null. The "service" publishes everything to the bus at any case.